# How create google script to find files from folder path by parameter?

Tags: javascript, file, google-apps-script, google-sheets, directory

my drive has a list of folders. Some of these folders were shared with me. Example:

```
/images
    logo.PNG
    mimdmap.jpg
/projects (shared)
    /webproject1
        doc1.doc
        finance_2017.xlsx
```

I would like to create a function as follows:

```
function listFolderFiles(path, file, callback){
var founded = false;
//google drive validate if entire folder exist
var pathCheck = ?

    If(pathCheck == false){
        return callback (false);
    }else{
  //google drive script to return files list object 
        var filesList = ?
        //loop to find file
      for(var i=0;i<filesList.size();i++){
            if(filesList[0].name == file){
                founded = true;
            }
        }
 return callback(founded)
}

listFolderFiles("/projects/webproject1", "doc1.doc", function (ret){
Looger.log(ret);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this answer? Please think of this as one of several answers. Each file and folder in Google Drive have the information of parent folder. So you can use retrieve files using this. In your question, it seems that there are no same folder names. So I propose a method which used this.

#### Sample script :

```
function listFolderFiles(path, file, callback) {
  var folders = ~path.indexOf("/") ? path.split("/") : [path];
  var folder = DriveApp.getFoldersByName(folders[folders.length - 1]);
  var folder = folder.hasNext() ? folder.next() : null;
  if (folder) {
    var files = folder.getFiles();
    while (files.hasNext()) {
      var f = files.next();
      if (f.getName() == file) {
        return callback(true);
      }
    }
    return callback(false);
  } else {
    return callback(false);
  }
}

function main() {
  listFolderFiles("/projects/webproject1", "doc1.doc", function (ret){Logger.log(ret)});
}
```

#### Note :

- When you use this script, please run `main()` function.
- In this sample script, since the information of parent folder for each file and folder is used, the paths of "/projects/webproject1" and "webproject1" get the same result.

If this was not useful for you, I'm sorry.

Comment: what does `~` mean in `~path.indexOf("/")`?

Comment: @Max Makhrov I'm sorry for the inconvenience. That means the inversion operator. When ``path`` includes ``/``, ``path.indexOf("/")`` is -1. ``~-1`` means 0. So when this is used for ``if``, zero works as true. Of course, you can also use ``path.indexOf("/") == -1`` instead of that.

Comment: 1) dont returning folders from my drive
  var folders = ~path.indexOf("/") == -1 ? path.split("/") : [path];
  var folder = DriveApp.getFoldersByName(folders[folders.length - 1]);
2) DriveApp.getFoldersByName havent getFiles metod

Comment: @fredericoallan  I'm sorry for the inconvenience. Can you show us your current script and your input parameters? If you can do, please add it to your question. Since in my environment, I have confirmed that the script works, I thought that that is required to understand your situation.

Comment: @Max Makhrov I have to apologize you about my reply comment. Now I noticed that I had misunderstood the situation. For example, ``"abc".indexOf("b")`` is 1. ``~1`` is -2. ``"abc".indexOf("d")`` is -1. ``~-1`` is 0. In javascript, 0 can be used as false. So I used ``~path.indexOf("/")`` for using as true when ``/`` is included in ``path``. On the other hand, when ``/`` is not included in ``path``, ``!~path.indexOf("/")`` can be used.

Comment: tks for help.
`
path="/SOFTBOX/TH"
file="doc1 - 12-02-2017"
`
my script is the same

`
...
  var folders = ["", "SOFTBOX", "TH"]
  var folder = Object (1940375782)
  var folder = Object (1940522829)
`
my return is always `false`

Comment: @Tanaike we have a problem. I have two TH folders. /SOFTBOX/TH and /TEMP/TH. in this case function return true for file that exist only in /TEMP/TH

Comment: @fredericoallan I'm sorry for the inconvenience. It seems that your additional comments are different for your initial question. My answer works for your initial question. So can you update your question? I would like to understand correctly your situation. By the way, can I ask you about ``var folders = ["", "SOFTBOX", "TH"]``, ``var folder = Object (1940375782)`` and ``var folder = Object (1940522829)``?